# VSCode not autoformatting on save (python - black)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have the following code in settings.json

```
{ 
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "python.black-formatter",
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--rcfile=${workspaceFolder}/.pylintrc"
    ],
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

I have installed the following extensions:

```
"ms-python.pylint"
"ms-python.black-formatter"
```

I have a .venv in the workspace with black and pylint installed.

vscode recognizes pylint errors, but doesn't format the code with the black rules?

Comment: Have you try to increase the Format on Save Timeout in Text Editor -> Formatting. i'm aware it can cause trouble if the save time out is too short.

Comment: I don't watch that option and if a i set that option is not recognice in settings.json.

Comment: erf ... Otherwise is it still happening when you disable extensions ? If a extension cause a conflict you can track it down using "Developer: Show Running Extensions" to see which extensions are active when the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1):

> "editor.formatOnSave": false,

Change **false** to **true**. And delete the following code:

> ```
> "[python]": {
>     "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
>     "editor.formatOnSave": true
> },
> ```

1. Run the command `pip install black` in your terminal.
2. Add the following code to your `setting.json`:

   "python.formatting.provider": "black",

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: Delete the additional extensions you installed. This is not the official extension of Microsoft

Comment: was a typo i hade installed python.black-formatter anyway doesnt work too.